# TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined react map function

Tags: reactjs, flux

```
    Post component
    ---------------


    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import * as PostActions from "../actions/PostActions";
    import PostStore from "../store/PostStore";

    class Post extends Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.loadPosts();
        this.getPosts = this.getPosts.bind(this);
        this.state = {
          post: []
        };
      }

      componentWillMount() {
        PostStore.on("change", this.getPosts);
      }

      componentWillUnmount() {
        PostStore.removeListener("change", this.getPosts);
      }

      getPosts() {
        this.setState({
          post: PostStore.getAll()
        });
      }

      loadPosts() {
        PostActions.fetchPosts();  // Action 
      }

      render() {
        const postItems = this.state.post.map(post => (
          <div key={post.id}>
            <h3>{post.title}</h3>
            <p>{post.body}</p>
          </div>
        ));

        return (
          <div>
            <h1>Posts</h1>
            {postItems}
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default Post;

----------------------------------------------
```

IN Console
    -------------------

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
>           at Post.jsx:35
>           at Array.map ()
>           at Post.render (Post.jsx:34)
>           at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:13537)
>           at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:13500)
>           at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:14089)
>           at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:16415)
>           at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:16453)
>           at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:145)
>           at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:195)
>           at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:248)
>           at replayUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:15744)
>           at renderRoot (react-dom.development.js:16547)
>           at performWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:17386)
>           at performWork (react-dom.development.js:17294)
>           at performSyncWork (react-dom.development.js:17266)
>           at interactiveUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:17557)

Comment: Does anybody have any idea about this error.

Comment: codeshare.io/anrK0Y check this link this is the entire code

Comment: log is this https://codeshare.io/arrLDV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially the post is an empty array so doing map on it won't work. Check it's length, if the length is greater than zero and then do map.

You need to do something like below

```
const {post} = this.state;
const postItems = post.length > 0 && post.map(p => {
          return (<div key={p!= undefined && p.id}>
            <h3>{p!= undefined && p.title}</h3>
            <p>{p!= undefined && p.body}</p>
          </div>)
        });
```

Comment: Ok can you share the console log of PostStore.getAll() and where you are calling getPosts()? share the entire code

Comment: codeshare.io/anrK0Y check this link this is the entire code

Comment: Can't run that code. Just do console.log of PostStore.getAll() in getPosts and share the log

Comment: It worked i will give you my tick.But my question is how did it coming undefined. Any idea?

Comment: Also it's showing a warning like.      index.js:2178 Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `false`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.

Comment: Because your data contains undefined in first index. You should correct that in your backend end. Regarding key warning if your data contains unique id use it else use index as key

Answer (score 2):

You can do this.

```
const postItems = this.state.post.map((post, id) => (
  <div key={id}>
    <h3>{post.title}</h3>
    <p>{post.body}</p>
  </div>
));
```

Comment: How does this help. You are still doing map on empty array. also the data already has unique id why he has to add index as key which isn't recommended

Comment: i don't think they have id in post, if post is empty map will not iterate rt ?

Comment: Take a look at his code he is already adding id from data as a key <div key={post.id}>

Comment: its look like your state is not updated.  console this `PostStore.getAll()` and check weather are you getting data or not

Comment: i checked console.log(PostStore.getAll()) ,yes state is working fine . the problem is something else

Comment: share your log too.  is it a type of array ?

Comment: codeshare.io/anrK0Y check this link this is the entire code